# How to exclude a class constructor using a dotCover filter?

Tags: dotcover

What should go in the "Function mask" field in dotCover's "Edit Coverage Filter" dialog? I've tried "Foo" and "Foo*" with no effect.

example:

```
public class Foo
{
  public Foo(int x, int y)
  {
     // how can I exclude this code from the code coverage calculation?
  }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it's worth mentioning that dotCover analyses complied assemblies, not the source code, to generate its coverage reports. Any C# constructor (irrespective of its name in C#) is compiled into a method named `.ctor` (or `.cctor` if the constructor is static). That's why dotCover will never see a method called `Foo(int, int)` in your example.

If you want to filter out the constructors of the `Foo` class, you need to type the following in "Edit Coverage Filter" dialog:

- Module Mask: *YourNamespace*
- Class Mask: *YourNamespace*.`Foo`
- Function Mask: `.ctor`

Hope this helps.

Comment: If the class had another constructor eg `public Foo(string a, string b)` is it possible to on filter 1 of the them?

Comment: @McBainUK: I don't think it is possible, the filter doesn't support specifying method signatures, as far as I know.

Comment: @IgorKorkov: I came to the same conclusion. Thanks for your help.